# Chrome API extension not intentionally downloading all Download History

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have created a Chrome Extension that reroutes downloads from a given website and places them into a specific folder with an extracted number from the URL. It does this
by listening for the "onCreated" event for downloads in Chrome, and it modifies the download URL and file name if the URL starts with the given website.

My issue is, when this Extension is active and I start up Chrome the Download History automatically starts downloading. The only way I was able to fix this was to clear the Download History, which is not ideal if I want to pass this out to people and I am not sure if this will crop up again. I have tried adding a "chrome.downloads.erase" into my code but this did not help unfortunately.

I'm really confused as to why this happens, my code doesn't touch the Download History. Does anyone with a better understanding of Chrome and it's API have any idea's to why this is happening?

Thanks,

Jordan

My code:

**service-worker.js**

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(downloadItem) {


    console.log("Download has been triggered");




    //Checks for downloads from Example.com
  if (downloadItem.url.startsWith("https.www.example.com")){ 
        console.log("The download is from Example.com");

        //need to cancel original download
        chrome.downloads.cancel(downloadItem.id)

        //Gets ID of Current Tab
        var currentTab
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs1){
        currentTab = tabs1[0];                      

        //Splits URL into an Array so it can pull Case Number
        const myArray = currentTab.url.split("/");
        let CaseNumber = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
        console.log("Case Number:", CaseNumber);


        //Splits URL into an Array so it can pull File Name
        const myArray1 = downloadItem.url.split("/")
        let NewFileName = myArray1[myArray1.length - 1] 
        
        
        //Sets Directory and adds Case Number to it
        const dir = "Cases\\"
        let FullPath = dir.concat(CaseNumber);
        //console.log(FullPath);

        //Adds the Filename to the Path
        let FileNameAndPath = FullPath.concat("\\");
        FileNameAndPath = FileNameAndPath.concat(NewFileName)


        //remove File from Downloads of Chrome
        chrome.downloads.erase({id: downloadItem.id}, function() {      
        });

        console.log("Path:", FileNameAndPath);

            //Sets download location and filename
            
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: downloadItem.finalUrl,
                filename: FileNameAndPath,          
            });

        }); 

    }

});
```

Comment: Judging by your description Chrome mistakenly fires chrome.downloads.onCreated for completed downloads, which is probably a bug. You can report it in https://crbug.com. The solution might be to check downloadItem.state.

Comment: @JordanSimpson - The `chrome.downloads.onCreated` listener aborts the current download and creates a new one, which should again trigger the `chrome.downloads.onCreated` listener. How do you prevent this from causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm you were right! Checking the downloadItem.state resolved this

Comment: @ThomasMueller In my case the downloadItem.url and downloadItem.finalUrl are completely different, so when the code is triggered on the second loop using the finalUrl it will not actually go into the IF Statement.